# C# if then else issues

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I'm getting the error Invalid expression term `else`.  Also an error by the bracket before else that says

> "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement".

```
public partial class frmPersonnel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime dt1;
            DateTime dt2;

        if (txtFirstName.Text == "")
        {
            txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            lblError.Text = "Please enter first name";
        }
        if (txtLastName.Text == "")
        {
            txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            lblError.Text = "Please enter last name!";
        }
        if (txtPayRate.Text == "")
        {
            txtPayRate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            lblError.Text = "Please enter pay rate!";
        }
        if (txtStartDate.Text == "")
        {
            txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            lblError.Text = "Please enter start date!";
        }
        if (txtEndDate.Text == "")
        {
            txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            lblError.Text = "Please enter end date!";
        }
         dt1 = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
         dt2 = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text);


        if (DateTime.Compare(dt1, dt2) > 0)
        {
            txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            lblError.Text = "Start Date must not be greater than End Date.";
        }
        }
      catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Please enter valid data!";
      }

        else
        {
            Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
            Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
            Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
            Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
            Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;
            Server.Transfer("frmPersonalVerified.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see too many closing brackets. This seems not to be the complete code

Comment: You are missing some of important code. Where is your "try"?

Comment: You just have your "{" and "}" mismatched. Thats all. Where is the "if" corresponding to the "else" - since they cant straddle the "try ... catch" blocks

Comment: fact is you want to put an else outside the try condition that contains the if... sleep more dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your braces and try{} catch{} blocks are mismatched. Here is the corrected code:**

```
public partial class frmPersonnel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime dt1;
            DateTime dt2;

            if (txtFirstName.Text == "")
            {
                txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text = "Please enter first name";
            }
            if (txtLastName.Text == "")
            {
                txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text = "Please enter last name!";
            }
            if (txtPayRate.Text == "")
            {
                txtPayRate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text = "Please enter pay rate!";
            }
            if (txtStartDate.Text == "")
            {
                txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text = "Please enter start date!";
            }
            if (txtEndDate.Text == "")
            {
                txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text = "Please enter end date!";
            }
            dt1 = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
            dt2 = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text);


            if (DateTime.Compare(dt1, dt2) > 0)
            {
                txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text = "Start Date must not be greater than End Date.";
            }

            else
            {
                Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
                Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
                Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
                Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
                Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;
                Server.Transfer("frmPersonalVerified.aspx");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Please enter valid data!";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax is wrong, you have a catch and no try, you could do it this way instead. Alhough why exactly are you catching an exception? Is it because you think the date's won't be there? If so, check that in the if instead waiting to catch an exception on the compare. Exceptions should only be used in **exceptional** circumstances. To fix the syntax in your post, do the following (Note that a finally occurs whether or not the exception was thrown)

```
     try
     {
        if (DateTime.Compare(dt1, dt2) > 0)  
        {  
            txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;  
            lblError.Text = "Start Date must not be greater than End Date.";  
        }  
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Please enter valid data!";
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         lblError.Text = "Please enter valid data!";
     }
     finally
     {
        Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;    
        Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;    
        Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;    
        Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;    
        Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;    
        Server.Transfer("frmPersonalVerified.aspx");
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dt1;
            DateTime dt2;
            lblError.Text = "";

            //Increment lblError.Text to see all errors

            if (txtFirstName.Text == "")
            {
                txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter first name";
            }
            if (txtLastName.Text == "")
            {
                txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter last name!";
            }
            if (txtPayRate.Text == "")
            {
                txtPayRate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter pay rate!";
            }
            if (txtStartDate.Text == "")
            {
                txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter start date!";
            }
            if (txtEndDate.Text == "")
            {
                txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter end date!";
            }

            try
            {
                //This is only to cacth parse erros from string to datetime
                dt1 = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
                dt2 = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text);

                if (DateTime.Compare(dt1, dt2) > 0)
                {
                    txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                    lblError.Text = "Start Date must not be greater than End Date.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                lblError.Text = "Please enter valid data!";
            }


            //Do wathever you want next
            //If this is only to get called with no errors you could validate if lblError.Text is empty
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblError.Text))
            {
                Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
                Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
                Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
                Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
                Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;
                Server.Transfer("frmPersonalVerified.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                //?
            }
        }
```

Comment: But the code in the `try` block is not likely to throw an exception, especially due to invalid data.

Comment: @DivHenr: Unless there is some other mismatched "{" and "}" in other sections of you code file, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this block per se. Check other functions above or below this. And also the class and namespace opening and closing braces

Comment: The accepted solution works but there is no logic in your code. First you only see the last error you are always overriding lblError.Text, second only if the date is ok you redirect? Very strange code!

Answer (score 2):

The last `else` block after the `catch` block has no corresponding `if` block.

Its hard to guess when the code in the else block is intended to execute. Give me a hint and i might show you the right place :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a `try` statement matching your `catch` - is that just a typo in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the else inside the try/catch, Please post the try to make it easier next time

Answer (score 1):

These lines are places incorrectly

```
 }       
 catch (Exception ex)
 { 
      lblError.Text = "Please enter valid data!";       
 }
```

eithe remove those lines OR add `try` construct.

Answer (score 1):

Move the second bracket before else key word